# How to align two overlayed plots, one being rotated?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, alignment, overlay

I have two plots which I want to present on a single figure.

[image]

The bottom left corner is a point of origin of the first plot. The top right corner is a point of origin of the second plot. Also, the second plot's axes have reversed directions. That image presents those two plots - the rightmost function belongs to the second plot.

I am using `Epilog->Inset[Rotate[plot2,180 Degree]]`. The result I posted was obtained after tweaking `ImageSize`, `ImagePadding`, `AspectRatio` and `Inset` coordinates with some arbitrary numbers. Is there a different, perhaps more elegant way?

**edit**: Code snippet:

```
T = {{"100", 12.23, 2.675, 1}, {"140", 35.2, 3.5, 1.4}, {"180", 81.3,4.275, 1.9}, 
     {"220", 162, 5.05, 2.4}, {"260", 288, 5.8,2.9}, {"300", 451, 6.4, 3.3}, 
     {"340", 674, 7, 3.8}, {"360", 818,7.25, 4.1}, {"400", 1160, 7.825, 4.6}};

p1 = Plot[(Pi^2*205*10^9*T[[2, 2]]*10^(-8)/x^2)/1000, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 1000,
       PlotRange -> {0, 3000}, ImagePadding -> {{6, 5}, {5, 6}}, AspectRatio -> 0.595];

Show[Table[{
            Plot[(Pi^2*205*10^9*T[[n, 2]]*10^(-8)/x^2)/1000, {x, 0,T[[n,3]]},
                 PlotStyle -> {Thick}],
            Plot[(Pi^2*205*10^9*T[[n, 2]]*10^(-8)/x^2)/1000, {x, T[[n,3]],10}, 
                PlotStyle -> {Dashed}]}
         , {n, Dimensions[T][[1]]}],
     PlotRange -> {0, 3000}, GridLines -> {Range[0, 10, 1], Range[0, 3000, 100]},
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed], ImageSize -> 1000,  
     ImagePadding -> {{6, 5}, {5, 6}}, 
     Epilog -> {
        Table[Inset[Framed[T[[n, 1]], RoundingRadius -> 10, Background -> White], 
                    {T[[n, 4]], 250*T[[n, 4]]}],
             {n,Dimensions[T][[1]]}],
        Inset[Rotate[p1, 180 Degree], {5.01, 1490}]
                }
     ]
```

Comment: Hello. I always find a pice of code something extra motivating to start to work on solution :)

Comment: I was a little hesitant, since like I said, the current solution is terribly rough and full of arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Please tell me if 1) ticks for reversed plot should be upside down? 2) what is Your main goal, maybe there is no need for so many operations.

Comment: Thanks for the interest! 1. Nope, the whole figure should be readable from just one side. 2. My goal is to compress information from a number of figures and secondary algorithms into as little space as possible. The result will be a pocket-size guide of sorts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following solution is almost fully automatic, You only have to pay attention to `ticks`.
Main idea is to use `ImagePadding` with `Overlay`. Reversed `Ticks` are created automatically.

```
T = {{"100", 12.23, 2.675, 1}, {"140", 35.2, 3.5, 1.4}, {"180", 81.3,4.275, 1.9}, 
 {"220", 162, 5.05, 2.4}, {"260", 288, 5.8,2.9}, {"300", 451, 6.4, 3.3}, 
 {"340", 674, 7, 3.8}, {"360", 818,7.25, 4.1}, {"400", 1160, 7.825, 4.6}};
f[x_, t_] := (Pi^2*205*10^9*t*10^(-8)/x^2)/1000
```

**Edit:** I have replaced first answer with a little bit clearer version with consistent ticks, the idea is the same:

```
Module[{ran = {{0, 10}, {0, 3000}}, ticks},
 ticks = Fold[#2 /@ #1 &, Reverse@ran,
             {FindDivisions[#, 50] &,
              {#, Flatten@Riffle[#[[;; ;; 5]], {Table["", {4}]}]} &,
              Transpose /@ {#, {#[[1]], Reverse@#[[2]]}} &}];
With[{
 options = Sequence[ImagePadding->30, ImageSize->800, AspectRatio->1, Axes->False,
                    PlotRange -> ran],
 plotopt = Sequence[PlotStyle -> {Thick, {Thick, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> ran],
 showopt = Sequence[GridLines -> {Range[0, 10, 1], Range[0, 3000, 100]}, Frame -> True, 
                FrameTicks->ticks, GridLinesStyle->Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed]]
},
Overlay[{
  Show[Plot[{If[x<#3, f[x,#2]], If[x>#3, f[x,#2]]}, {x,ran[[1,1]], ran[[1,2]]}, 
            plotopt] & @@@T,
       options, showopt],
  Rotate[#, Pi] &@Plot[f[x, T[[2, 2]]], {x, 0, 10}, options, PlotStyle -> Thick]
       }]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Since `ImagePadding` does not care about `FrameLabels` etc. one can simply add those to `showopt` (*larger* `ImagePadding` *required in order to include them*). Also `AspectRatio` can be modyfied with no harm:

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks a dozen! Your rework is a hundred times more elegant and readable than mine. I greatly appreciate your help. Dzieki!

Comment: @rythin I'm glad You like it. Take a look at remark I've added. I have also corrected small mistake in the code, reversed plot was without proper `PlotRange`, now it is good.