# Passing list of options to Plot

Tags: expression-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to create a variable that I can use to hold all of the graphics directives for, say, a plot command.  For example, I have 8 plots with variations on the following:

```
Plot[{Im[eppar[400*10^12, t, 0.1]],
      Im[eppar[400*10^12, t, 0.2]], 
      Im[eppar[400*10^12, t, 0.5]], 
      Im[eppar[400*10^12, t, 0.8]]
     }, {t, tlow, thigh}, (**directives**)]
```

There's a fairly long list of directives I'm using for the plots, and I'd like to avoid having to modify 8 long, complicated expressions every time I want to change anything.  Does anybody know of a solution to this? It would make my code much cleaner.

Comment: You can use `With` like [in here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28100/5478).

Comment: Can you give us a clearer idea what you have in mind when you say "avoid having to modify 8 long, complicated expressions every time I want to change anything"? And I think we would like to see the "8 long, complicated expressions" and definition or `eppar` so we can work with your code.

Comment: I think you may simply be looking for `Directive`.

Comment: Closely related: [(20718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121) (`setSpec` in my second answer is directly applicable.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Guys, **this is *not* a duplicate of [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/pass-list-of-options-to-plot3d) question** (somehow my comment was deleted). That question was about how options are passed to `HoldAll` functions, but the question asked here is *not* about that technicality. It is much closer (may be a dupe) to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/custom-functions-by-delegating-options-in-a-specific-way-and-using-core-function/). I hope I won't have to repeat this comment a third time (i.e this one won't get deleted).

Comment: @Leonid your comment was deleted by Community♦ probably when the question was closed because it contained the word "duplicate."  That seems overly aggressive to me.

Comment: @Leonid I don't know if I agree with you.  I also linked 20718 which includes an UpValues method that might be closer to this question.  Your answer/proposed duplicate looks a lot more heavy duty than what this question calls for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I disagree. I think that the essence of the question is exactly what was discussed in the question I linked, namely, how to create persistent option configurations where several options are set to certain values. The fact that the function is queston happens to be `Plot` and therefore option-passing has additional subtleties, seems of a secondary importance to me, given the exact wording of the question.

Comment: @Leonid Do you think this question should be reopened, or closed as a duplicate of (22697)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know. This one looks pretty close to that one, so we might as well close as a dupe of that one, but I wouldn't insist on closing. But the one currently marked as the master question for this one, is not it - that's where I have a strong opinion.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but why not just use `SetOptions[Plot, Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green},
 Frame -> True];` ?? You could even define a function `setSpec` that performs this `SetOptions`, and then other `setspec2` that sets options differently, to your heart's content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way using `Evaluate`:

```
ops1 = {Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Frame -> True};

Plot[{Sin[x] + x/2, Sin[x] + x}, {x, 0, 10}
      , Evaluate@ops1
      , PlotLabel -> Style["Using Evaluate", 20]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On Leonid's valued opinion that the Close was inappropriate I have reopened this question.

By my interpretation this does what is requested:

```
SetAttributes[setSpec, HoldAllComplete]

setSpec[s_Symbol, spec__] := s /: h_[pre__, s, post___] := h[pre, spec, post]
```

The usage is:

```
setSpec[ops1,
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green},
 Frame -> True
]
```

Now:

```
Plot[{Sin[x] + x/2, Sin[x] + x}, {x, 0, 10}, ops1]
```

[image]

Because `Plot` handles both `Plot[. . ., option1, option2, . . .]` and `Plot[. . ., {option1, option2, . . .}]` you can use either form in `setSpec`.

`setSpec` can also be configured to apply to only certain heads, e.g.:

```
SetAttributes[setSpecFor, HoldAllComplete]

setSpecFor[head_Symbol, s_Symbol, spec__] := s /: head[pre__, s, post___] := head[pre, spec, post]
```

And usage would be: `setSpecFor[Plot, ops1, (* options *)]`

This allows you to use the same name (Symbol) for separate options for different plot types.